# How to get parameters in an url after last occurrence of a certain character

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, substring

Currently I have some jquery which is getting some parameters from the URL by getting all required parameters after a '#' in the URL. My URL has more than one # therefore I would like it to only select the parameters from after the last # in the URL. So far I have the below (which selects all occurrences of the #). Any ideas on how I can achieve what I want?

```
params = url.substring(url.indexOf('#') + 1, url.length);
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `lastIndexOf()` method.

```
params = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('#') + 1, url.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

since you want params after last #

try this

```
params = url.split('#');
alert(params[params.length-1]);
```